# MVC 3 validate Date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, validation

I want to validate DateTime in (dd/mm/yyyy) format in client as well as server in MVC 3.

Please provide any guidelines / suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a jquery Date Popup, then you can set the format in the popup itself and make the textbox readonly.

Other hard way is to validate on submission with a regular expression. You can get lots of regex's if you search through google. Here is one [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html) for you.